# Header dateClick is not firing/working in full calendar v5

Tags: fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar v5 version and rendering the events with `resourceTimeGrid`

After rendering my view is looking like this
[image]

When I tried to click on the date its not going to dayView. Even if I put console log the click event is not getting fired

I tried with following events but none of them is working,

First tried with dateClick

```
 dateClick: function(info) {
    alert('Clicked on: ' + info.dateStr);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('Current view: ' + info.view.type);
    // change the day's background color just for fun
    info.dayEl.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
```

After that removed the date click and tried with `navLinkDayClick`

```
 navLinks: true,
  navLinkDayClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
    console.log('day', date.toISOString());
    console.log('coords', jsEvent.pageX, jsEvent.pageY);
  }
```

Both of them is not working.
I feel the above two events inside the calendar.
I am not able to find any events related to headerDateClick in full calendar v5

In fullcalendar V3, everything is working fine with adding any events and not sure why its not working in V5

Comment: My bad looked into wrong events. Acheived this by  `dayHeaderDidMount: function (arg) {
         arg.el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          self.calendar.changeView('timeGridDay');
          self.calendar.gotoDate( arg.date )
         });
      },`